# Amount of a specific letter counter

Tags: javascript

How will I make a script that will count the number of a specific letter in a Lorem text? Like if I type d in the chat box it will display a number in the div of how many d’s there are in the text.

Comment: Loop through each character, and count them.

Comment: This is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/twinbird24/pn4h2zux/

Answer (score 0):

You can go through each character in the string, and use an associative array to keep a running tally.  Then output the key and value of that associative array.